# How to Prove the Sum of Absolute Values is greater than or equal to Absolute Value of Sum

Tags: summation, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i| \geq |\sum_{i=1}^nx_i| \forall \bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Intuitively, I know this is true. I also can provide counter examples to say that $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$ cannot always be less than $|\sum_{i=1}^nx_i|$, and the two terms are not always equal to one another, but I don't know how to prove the $\geq$ relationship.

Are disproving the other two possiblities enough to prove a $\geq$ relationship? If not, can anyone help me figure out where to start proving it?

Comment: start with proving the triangle inequality then use induction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: You cannot "provide counter examples to say that $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ cannot be less than $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right|$". You can provide examples for which $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ is greater than or equal to $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right|$, but those examples cannot prove the inequality in general.